# Refactor an IO recursive loop into a monad folding in Haskell

Tags: sockets, haskell, network-programming, io-monad

I writing a tcp server, and here's my main loop method:

```hs
serverLoop :: Socket -> IO ()
serverLoop sock = do
    (conn, _) <- accept sock
    forkIO $ handleConn conn
    serverLoop sock
```

(Note: `handleConn :: Socket -> IO ()` is a function specific to my program.)

I would like to refactor that into a more *monadic* way, here's my tentative:

```hs
serverLoop :: Socket -> IO ()
serverLoop sock = foldl1 (>>) $ map go $ repeat sock
     where go sock = (accept sock) >>= (forkIO . handleConn . fst) >> return ()
```

But this makes the program crash as soon as I start sending data through the socket.

Here are my questions: why? what's the fix for that?

Comment: Why are you using `foldl` instead of [`foldM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM)?

Comment: What do you mean by "more monadic"?

Comment: I think the `foldl1` is the culprit for the crash - you cannot usefully left fold over an infinite list, it will loop infinitely or raise an exception, and might run out of memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idiomatic way to repeat the same action over and over again forever is [`forever`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:forever)

```
serverLoop :: Socket -> IO ()
serverLoop sock = forever $ do
    (conn, _) <- accept sock
    forkIO $ handleConn conn
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "more monadic", but your function can be written this way:

```
serverLoop :: Socket -> IO ()
serverLoop sock = forever (accept sock >>= forkIO . handleConn . fst)
```